# SQL Case Statement with Subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query to report on how many times a part was used during a specific month. For example, take February as the reporting month. If P1 was installed on A1 until 2014-02-05 and was used within 2014-02-01 to 2014-02-05 then I would need to Sum that up. Also if P1 was installed on A2 then I would need to sum up the usage up to 2014-02-28.

```
| part | date_trans | transaction | unit |
---------------------------------------------
  p1     2014-02-05    removed        A1
  p1     2014-02-07    installed      A2

| unit | daily usage | date |
   A1       3         2014-02-01
   A1       2         2014-02-03
   A2       2         2014-02-05
   A2       4         2014-02-08
   A2       2         2014-02-20
```

Notice for the record

```
| unit | daily usage | date |
  A2       2         2014-02-05
```

We do not need to take account because P1 was not installed on A2 on 2014-02-05.

Here is my attempt so far..

```
SELECT     
CASE
WHEN h.date_trans between '2014-01-31' and '2014-02-28' and transaction='removed' THEN...
END AS 'test'
FROM history h join acu on(acu.unit=h.unit)
WHERE h.part='P1'
```

Comment: what error you are getting from your query?

Comment: I haven't been able to complete the query yet, this is where I am stuck. If the case statement is met, how does it know to SUM([daily usage]) for each respective part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following query, using CTE's:

```
with history_installed as
(select part, 
case
  when date_trans <= '2014-02-01' then '2014-02-01'
  else date_trans 
end date_trans
from history
where transaction = 'installed' and date_trans < '2014-03-01') 
, history_removed as
(select part, 
case
  when date_trans >= '2014-02-28' then '2014-02-28'
  else date_trans
end date_trans
from history
where transaction = 'removed' and date_trans >= '2014-02-01')
select acu.*
from acu
inner join history_installed on history_installed.date_trans <= acu.date
inner join history_removed on history_removed.date_trans >= acu.date
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
/*
create table #t1 (part char(2), date_trans date, trans char(10), unit char(2))
go
insert #t1 values
('p1',     '2014-02-05',    'removed'  ,      'A1'),
('p1',     '2014-02-07' ,   'installed',      'A2')
go
create table #t2 (unit char(2), usage int, dt date)
go
insert #t2 values
(   'A1',       3,         '2014-02-01'),
(   'A1',       2,         '2014-02-03'),
(   'A2',       2,         '2014-02-05'),
(   'A2',       4,         '2014-02-08'),
(   'A2',       2,         '2014-02-20')
*/


declare @min date = '20140201', @max date = '20140228'
;with x as (
    select *,
    isnull(case trans when 'removed' then lag(date_trans) over(partition by part order by date_trans) else date_trans end, @min) as date_start,
    isnull(case trans when 'installed' then lead(date_trans) over(partition by part order by date_trans) else date_trans end, @max) as date_end
    from #t1
)
select #t2.unit, x.part, sum(#t2.usage)
from #t2
inner join x on #t2.dt between x.date_start and x.date_end
and x.unit = #t2.unit
group by #t2.unit, x.part

-- drop table #t1, #t2
```

Here's the query for the older (pre-2012) versions:

```
;with x as (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by part order by date_trans) as rn
    from #t1
),
y as (
    select x1.*,
    case x1.trans when 'removed' then isnull(x2.date_trans, @min) else x1.date_trans end as date_start,
    case x1.trans when 'installed' then isnull(x3.date_trans, @max) else x1.date_trans end as date_end
    from x x1
    left outer join x x2 on x1.rn = x2.rn+1
    left outer join x x3 on x1.rn = x3.rn-1
)
select #t2.unit, y.part, sum(#t2.usage)
from #t2
inner join y on #t2.dt between y.date_start and y.date_end
and y.unit = #t2.unit
group by #t2.unit, y.part
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but Lag is a not a recognized function. I am using MS SQL Server 2008.

Comment: You didn't specify the version, so I assumed the current.